# Simplest way to check if a string converted to a number is actually a number in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Not sure if this makes sense, but I need to check if a server value returned is actually a number. Right now I get ALL number values returned as strings
ie '7'  instead of 7.

What's the simplest way to check if string values can actually be converted to numbers?

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way to do this is to actually convert the string to a Number and test to see if it's NaN. If you look at the Flex API reference, the top-level Number() function says it will return NaN if the string passed to the method cannot be converted to a Number.

Fortunately, Flex (sort of) does this for you, with the isNaN() function. All you need to do is:

```
var testFlag:Boolean = isNaN( someStringThatMightBeANumber );
```

If `testFlag` is false, the string can be converted to a number, otherwise it can't be converted.

**Edit**

The above will not work if compiling in strict mode. Instead, you will need to first convert to Number and then check for NaN, as follows:

```
var testFlag:Boolean = isNaN( Number( someStringThatMightBeANumber ) );
```

Comment: OK, then we just convert to Number first. I'll make the appropriate edit.

Comment: I experimented with this briefly.  It seems you can use 'Number(someString) is Number' to perform the check?

Comment: Bear in mind that `isNaN("") == false`, probably because an empty string evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 16):

Haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
if( isNaN(theString) ) {
   trace("it is a string");
} else {
    trace("it is a number");
}
```

If you are using AS3 and/or strict mode (as pointed out by back2dos), you will need to convert to number first in order for it to compile:

```
if( isNaN(Number(theString)) ) {
   trace("it is a string");
} else {
    trace("it is a number");
}
```

Comment: the parameter of isNaN has to be a float ... so this will throw compiler errors in strict mode ...

Comment: true for as3 strict mode I suppose, although that was not specified. Hardly deserves a negative vote though dude - I mean, you voted down 3 posts here. How about just putting in a comment and leaving it at that. jeesh.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers on this question have a major flaw in them. If you take Number(null) or Number(undefined) or Number(""), all will return 0 and will evaluate to "is a number". Try something like this instead:

```
function isANumber( val:* ):Boolean {
    return !(val === null || val === "" || isNaN(val));
}
```

Comment: You should check for StringUtil.trim(val) === "" to cover the case of blank spaces.

Answer (score 3):

RegExp path :

```
function stringIsAValidNumber(s: String) : Boolean {
    return Boolean(s.match(/^[0-9]+.?[0-9]+$/));
}
```

Comment: OMG! there is a simple `isNan` function for that! Don't think hard! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to check if value can be converted to a number:

```
var ob:Object = {a:'2',b:3,c:'string'};

for( var v:* in ob){
 var nr:Number = ob[v];
 trace(ob[v]+" "+(nr === Number(nr)))
}
```

this will trace following:

```
2 true
3 true
string false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that in actionscript :

```
trace(int('7')); // will return 7
```

and

```
trace(int('a')); // will return 0
```

So except for zeros, you can actually now if a string is a number or not

Answer (score 0):

this will try to convert your `String` to a `Number`, which essentially is a 64 bit floating point number:

```
var val:Number = Number(sourceString);
```

if `sourceString` is not a valid `String` representation of a `Number`, val will be `NaN` (not a number) ... you have check against that value with `isNaN` ... because `val == NaN` will return false for a reason that can't quite understand ... you can use `int(val) == val` to check, whether it is an integral value ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 0):

```
function isANumber(__str:String):Boolean
{
    return !isNaN(Number(__str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into any function where you want only numbers to stay
joy_edit1 is a TextInput Object (spark)

```
//is a number check
if( isNaN(Number(joy_edit1.text)) ) {
  joy_edit1.text = "";
  return void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native solution of Adobe:

[parseInt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000590.html) and [parseFloat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000589.html#154142) methods.

Also read the isNaN description:

> Returns true if the value is NaN(not a number). The isNaN() function
>   is useful for checking whether a mathematical expression evaluates
>   successfully to a number. The most common use of isNaN() is to check
>   the value returned from the **parseInt**() and **parseFloat**() functions. The
>   NaN value is a special member of the Number data type that represents
>   a value that is "not a number."

Here is a simple implementation:

```
function isANumber(value:String):Boolean {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(value));
}
```

Comment: This method will also return true in case string contains number with random characters, example: 6s.

Answer (score -1):

```
typeof('7') == 'string'
typeof(7) == 'number'
```

Does that help?

Comment: not really, since it was about determining whether a string is numeric ... btw. this is deprecated since AS3, since it provides "is" operator (AS2 had "instanceof" for that matter), property "constructor" or "flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName"